# Ionic Angular Application: How to show slide index using swiper?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

can anyone tell me why the interpolation of the index property doesn’t work? the value remains fixed at 1.

.html

```
<swiper (slideChange)="onSlideChange($event)">   
  <ng-template *ngFor ="let image of this.images, let i = index" swiperSlide>
     <ion-list style="align-items:center">
        <ion-img class="image" [src]="image.data"></ion-img>
        <ion-label>{{image.name}}</ion-label>
     </ion-list>
  </ng-template>
</swiper> 
<ion-label>{{index}}/{{this.images.length}}</ion-label>
```

.ts

```
images = [....];
index = 1;
onSlideChange(event){
    this.index = event[0].activeIndex+1;
    console.log(this.index);
}
```

p.s the console prints the correct index value every (slideChange)

Comment: onSlideChange runs outside of the angular zone and therefore does not detect changes, you can use NgZone run method to reenter the angular zone and update the value https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run

Answer (score 0):

Use **NgZone**

.html

```
<swiper
  [slidesPerView]="1"
  [spaceBetween]="50"
  (swiper)="onSwiper($event)"
  (slideChange)="onSlideChange($event)"
>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  public index = 0;

  constructor(
    private _ngZone: NgZone
    ) { }

  onSlideChange(e) {
    const current_index = e[0].activeIndex;
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this._increaseProgress(current_index,() => {
        this._ngZone.run(() => { 
          // console.log('Outside Done!'); 
        });
      });
    });
    console.log("Prints current index on slide change",this.index)
  }

  _increaseProgress(current_index,doneCallback: () => void) {
    this.index = current_index;
    doneCallback();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You Can use getActiveIndex()
Read official documentation
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/slides/Slides/#getActiveIndex